# Where is the result of addition? Intel 8080

Tags: assembly, 8085, intel-8080

I can't understand the behavior of processing code for Intel 8080.
For example I want to add two hex numbers:
3H and 4H so I wrote:

```
MVI A, 3H
MVI B, 4H
ADD B
HLT
```

But where can I find the result after processing? Should I copy result from A to some memory address or what?
Sorry, but this is my first time with that kind of things and I can't see how does it works.

And for example, picture showing my example in 8085 Simulator.
[image: 8085 Simulator by J-Tech Softwares]

Another question is why some flags changed but registers stayed untouched?
Shouldn't `MVI B, 4H` change value of B-register?
If not, please explain how does it works.

After giving 2 bytes for each instruction accumulator also stayed with no result.
[image]

And it seems that the only instruction that could affect accumulator or any other registry is INR. Is it possible that "my" simulator has a defect and don't work properly?
[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can have an `MVI` at address 4000 and another at 4001, given that each `MVI` is two bytes in size.

Comment: Ok, but after correcting it the problem is still unsolved :/

Comment: The memory pane on the right seems to be showing addresses 0x4010 upwards?

Comment: Upper left corner address cell is ML:4010. Has it any meaning in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I could see from the screenshots, you are wrongly entering the code.
your final code is suppose to be like:

```
MVI A, 3H       ->   3E 03
MVI B, 4H       ->   06 04
ADD B           ->   80
HLT             ->   76
```

I haven't used this simulator but I suppose you are inputting wrong Mnemonics. I think it should be like:

```
Address    Mnemonics   M Code
Address1:  MVI A       3E
Address2:  3           03
Address3:  MVI B       06
Address4:  4           04
Address5:  ADD B       80
Address6:  HLT         76
```

And not like:

```
Address1: MVI A, 3
Address2: MVI B, 4
Address3: ADD B
Address4: HLT
```

(this is clear if we see the coloumn M. Code where `MVI A, 3` and `MVI B, 4` has got no opcodes)
Then only you will get the intended code as:

```
3E 03 06 04 80 76
```

What you are actually running till now was some `NOP` operations (opcode value `00`) and `HLT`. :-)

Comment: MVI A 03 is an example of working syntax. Thank you for a clue :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of

```
MVI A, 3H
MVI B, 4H
ADD B
```

Will have a result in register A.

The result of MVI B, 4H will be 4H in register B.

Comment: And I thought like so, but 8085 Simulator stayed with untouched A and B registers after finishig code. I don't understad that. Could you take a look of attached picture and tell me a clue of what is wrong there, please?